# Getting a JSON response with ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, ember.js

I am trying to do some experimenting with Ember js. Instead of fixtures I would like to use an API.

This is my code which I am using to get the data:

```
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON('http://someurl.json').then(function(data) {
            return data.items_popular.map(function(item) {
                return item;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This is what the json file looks like:

```
{
   "popular":{
      "items_popular":[
         {
            "id":"23",
            "item":"Some title",
            "url":"http://url",
            "user":"girl"
         },
         {
            "id":"56",
            "item":"Title of item 2",
            "url":"http://url",
            "user":"guy"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Currently I keep getting an

```
Cannot call method 'map' of undefined
```

Would appreciate any help with refactoring my request

Comment: `data.popular.items_popular`? http://jsfiddle.net/rmfRt/

Comment: @JasonP tried that too, -> Cannot read property 'items_popular' of undefined

Comment: I don't see you accessing an `items_last_week` property in what you've posted.

Comment: changed it and yes your comment solved it. Thanks a million an please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing `data.items_popular`, but it should be `data.popular.items_popular`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rmfRt/